# Insert html tags in mysql table with C#

Tags: asp.net, mysql, c#-4.0, html

i have this question about `mysql` data in a table... how can i insert an html text with tags, text, etc in a `mysql` table?
What datatype do i need to store something like that and what do i need to encode or whatever i need to perform the insert?
I'm using c# 4.0 and mysql connector 6.3.6

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate [How to store/retrieve HTML in MySQL using .Net (C#/VB)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710741/how-to-store-retrieve-html-in-mysql-using-net-c-vb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `TINYTEXT`, `TEXT`, `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT` [datatypes depending on how much data you are expecting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html).

If you are dealing with UTF-8 encoded html make sure that your collation matches that.

Comment: That works for me, thanks! I use to the HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode for passing the html data